# iOS8: Dictation keyboard disappears after adjusting view constraints

Tags: keyboard, ios8, dictation

We use constraints to adjust a view just before the keyboard appears.
The adjustement is performed on UIKeyboardWillShowNotification notification.

The problem is that when the user switches to "dictation" keyboard, the keyboard shows up and imiddiately disappears.
It seems like the problem is a result of an adjustment of a constraint (self.gapViewConstraint.constant = height) and only occurs on iOS8 (as-you-speak text recognition was added to iOS8).

Any ideas how can that be solved without removing the constraints?